# Why didn't Thor take Loki's staff with him?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

At the end of **The Avengers**, Thor takes Loki with him to Asgard as a prisoner. He also took the Tesseract. But why didn't he take Loki's staff? Seeing that S.H.I.E.L.D. used the Tesseract to make weapons of mass destruction, he will surely realize that the staff was of great power and earth's people could use it for making weapons. So why didn't he take the staff with him?

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer to a related question on [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89524/why-didnt-thor-take-the-sceptre-back-to-asgard):

> I don't believe that a reason was ever given. However, in light of the
>   other movies, I have a theory.
>
> After the events in New York, SHIELD took the scepter for "safe
>   keeping". Most likely under Fury's orders to determine its threat and
>   other uses. Given that HYDRA had successfully infiltrated SHIELD at
>   this point, the scepter was "lost" somewhere along the way. Either
>   that, or HYDRA took advantage of the events in Winter Soldier to steal
>   the scepter. Although, I believe the first is more likely, seeing as
>   how Strucker had been experimenting on folks for a while. But, it
>   probably wasn't until after SHIELD/HYDRA collapse that it was realized
>   to be missing. This could be done by sending falsified reports about
>   anything going on with the scepter. Again, since HYDRA was at all
>   levels of SHIELD, this would have been fairly simple to do. Especially
>   since the head of SHIELD himself was HYDRA.
>
> Sadly, this would have made a great Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. episode,
>   and they missed the opportunity. There was pretty much no lead up to
>   the fact that HYDRA had the scepter, except for the tiny credits scene
>   for Winter Soldier.

And on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/3sdq06/question_about_lokis_scepter_and_the_avengers/):

> I think the explanation comes at the the end of Winter Soldier.
>   Strucker in the mid-credits scene says that "it's worth more than any
>   of them ever knew." I assume the Avengers simply didn't realize how
>   powerful the scepter really was, so SHIELD just took it.

Comment: Why did Thor abandon the staff at first place?

Comment: @AsifIqubal Maybe because Space stone is more powerful than the Mind stone.

Comment: Good answer! While we are just speculating, I am wondering if folk thought that the scepters power was derived from the Tesseract, considering they had no idea the mind stone was encased in the gem (Cap. America - "It may be magical, but it works an awful lot like a Hydra weapon" given that that all of Zola's designs were powered by the Tesseract).